# Код не центируется, помогите

Tags: html, css, center

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
:root {
  --bg: #fff;
  --header: #DEDEDE;
  --shadow: #CECECE;
  --logo: #000;
  --hover: #009EAA;
  --name: #000;
  --social: #000;
  --navbar: #000;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
   :root {
    --bg: #232323;
    --header: #303030;
    --shadow: #1B1B1B;
    --logo: #fff;
    --hover: #009EAA;
    --name: #fff;
    --social: #fff;
    --navbar: #fff;
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

body {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: var(--bg);
  color: #fff;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10rem 9% 2rem;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 9%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 50px 1px var(--shadow, 0.15);
  background: var(--header);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  color: var(--logo);
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: default;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: var(--navbar);
  margin-left: 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s all ease;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: var(--shadow);
}

.home {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 60px;
}

.home-content h3:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.home-content h3 {
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--name);
}

span {
  color: var(--hover);
}

.home-content h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.social a {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: var(--social);
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.social a:hover {
  color: var(--hover);
}

a.active {
  color: var(--shadow);
}

.home-img img {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -10%;
  position: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
}

@media (max-width: 730px) {
  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
  }
  .home {
    font-size: 6px
  }
  .home-content {
    font-size: 6px
  }
  .home-content h3 {
    font-size: 30px
  }
  .home-content h1 {
    font-size: 17.5px;
  }
  .home-img {
    width: 450px;
  }
  .social a {
    font-size: 4rem;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="permach.su/" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="permach.su/">
  <meta property="og:title" content="permach.su/" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://permach.su/" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#262d39" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/icon.svg" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/icon.svg">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css" />
  <script src="https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/ff1dad20fbbf8656d57c7796bc393f32/settings/security_level"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <a href="https://permach.su/" class="logo">PERMACH</a>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="https://permach.su/" class="active">Главная</a>
      <a href="https://guilds.permach.su/" target="_blank">Гильдии</a>
      <a href="https://nohello.permach.su/" target="_blank">Мета</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="home-content">
      <div class="home-img">
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/687661528337350705/ed23e07561d21577674ee8be9131cd34.webp?size=1024&width=0&height=204" alt="permach_avatar" />
      </div>
      <h3>Permach</h3>
      <h1 style="color: #487878;">Jumping off a <span>window</span> is just an action.</h1>
      <div class="social">
        <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="bx bxl-discord"></i></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="bx bxl-steam"></i></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="bx bxl-telegram"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: то есть сам social в центр не идет, не работает

Comment: `.social { text-align:center; }`

Comment: `.social { display: grid; grid-auto-flow: column; justify-content: center; }`